# Odoo add_product_control open form view

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I want to open form view on click "Add a product" in purchase order form view, just like in sale order view. I literally don't know why in sale order view it works but in purchase order view it don't.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed `editable` attribute to `""` in `tree` in purchase order form view and it works ;)

```xml
    <record id="purchase_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="editable"></attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```